# Speakers and headphone paths (name of PCM device)

Tags: linux, audio, devices, alsa, pulseaudio

I am really confused trying to get my speakers and headphone device PCM names like a "hw:x,x" or something like that;

```
cat /proc/asound/devices    
  2: [ 0]   : control
  3: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  4: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
  5: [ 0- 3]: digital audio playback
  6: [ 0- 0]: hardware dependent
  7: [ 0- 2]: hardware dependent
 33:        : timer
```

So my question is... how to get all available PCM names of my audio card on Linux?

Thanks

p.s.

- os Linux Arch x64